# How to fix Package source mapping is off in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I found this message while installing some packages in Visual Studio 2022. [image]

So I clicked "Configure" the "Add" I found "nuget.org" but then I clicked on it, and the Add button not turned off.[image]

Comment: Try adding `*` as a pattern - _”`*` is the shortest allowed prefix pattern and matches all packages ids”_ - from [docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-source-mapping)

Answer (score 0):

Select a package from the list to show it in the Details Pane.
Press the Configure button to open the Package Source Mappings options page.

From the Visual Studio Options Dialog
Go to the Tools menu in the main Visual Studio toolbar, and choose NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings.
Navigate to the Package Source Mappings page.
Press the Add button in the Package Source Mappings page to open the Add Package Source Mappings dialog.
Enter a Package ID or Package Pattern, and select one or more package source(s) by toggling the checkbox for your desired source(s).
The Package Source Mapping options page will show the newly created source mapping.
Press OK on the Options Dialog to save changes to the applicable nuget.config.
The NuGet Package Manager window will refresh and reflect the new status of the selected package's source mappings.
If you still have any issue you can refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-source-mapping)

Answer (score 0):

You have to also specify a package (name) pattern of packages that should be mapped to the selected source. You can use `*` for all packages. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-source-mapping#enabling-package-source-mapping